# Python API Query + Email Notification

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x

I wrote this to query the Trello API to find the cards that haven't been updated in 7 days and send an email notification to the card's members as a digest.

I'm a Node.JS & client-side JS dev, and this is my first Python script. I'd really appreciate any suggestions around best practices, how it could be more modular/reusable, etc.

```
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from urllib import urlencode
import json
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
import pytz
import mandrill
from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader

# Load environment variables
dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

MIN_DAYS = os.environ.get("MIN_DAYS")
TRELLO_KEY = os.environ.get("TRELLO_KEY")
TRELLO_TOKEN = os.environ.get("TRELLO_TOKEN")
TRELLO_BOARD = os.environ.get("TRELLO_BOARD")
MANDRILL_KEY = os.environ.get("MANDRILL_KEY")
MSG_FROM_EMAIL = os.environ.get("MSG_FROM_EMAIL")
MSG_FROM_NAME = os.environ.get("MSG_FROM_NAME")
MSG_SUBJECT = os.environ.get("MSG_SUBJECT")
MEMBER_EMAILS = os.environ.get("MEMBER_EMAILS")

mandrill_client = mandrill.Mandrill(MANDRILL_KEY)

# Prepare template
template_env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader(__name__, "templates"))
template = template_env.get_template("reminder_email.html")

# Split member emails into a dict
member_emails = {}
member_email_lines = MEMBER_EMAILS.split(",")
for member_email_line in member_email_lines:
    member_email_line_parts = member_email_line.split(":")
    member_emails[member_email_line_parts[0].strip()] = member_email_line_parts[1].strip()

# Querystring parameters
params = {
    "key": TRELLO_KEY,
    "token": TRELLO_TOKEN,
    "fields": "name,url,dateLastActivity",
    "members": "true"
}

# Construct trello URL and fetch
url = "https://api.trello.com/1/boards/" + TRELLO_BOARD + "/cards?" + urlencode(params)
cards = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

today = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
members = {}

# For each card that's older than a week
for card in cards:
    dateLastActivity = dateutil.parser.parse(card[u'dateLastActivity'])
    if abs(today - dateLastActivity).days > int(MIN_DAYS):
        # Add card to each member's list
        for member in card[u'members']:
            username = str(member[u'username'])
            if username not in members:
                members[username] = []
            members[username].append(card)

# For each member
for username in members:
    if username in member_emails:
        # Build message data
        message = {
            "subject": MSG_SUBJECT,
            "from_email": MSG_FROM_EMAIL,
            "from_name": MSG_FROM_NAME or MSG_FROM_EMAIL,
            "to": [{
                "email": member_emails[username],
                "name": username,
                "type": "to"
            }],
            # Construct HTML from template
            "html": template.render(num_days=MIN_DAYS, cards=members[username])
        }

        # Send email
        try:
            result = mandrill_client.messages.send(message=message)
            print result
        except mandrill.Error, e:
            print 'A mandrill error occurred: %s - %s' % (e.__class__, e)
            raise
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good at a first glance.  For reusability the code should be
divided into functions instead of just being a single script file.

- I'd load the multiple environment keys in a loop and into a separate
  dictionary instead of globals.  That's nicer to refactor later and
  it's easy to pass around, or even update from command line arguments
  as well (e.g. using `argparse`).  You can also look at
  [`dotmap`](https://github.com/drgrib/dotmap) or something similar to
  get a bit nicer syntax.  E.g.:

  ```python
  options = {}
  for name in ["MIN_DAYS",
              "TRELLO_KEY",
              "TRELLO_TOKEN",
              "TRELLO_BOARD",
              "MANDRILL_KEY",
              "MSG_FROM_EMAIL",
              "MSG_FROM_NAME",
              "MSG_SUBJECT",
              "MEMBER_EMAILS"]:
      options[name] = os.environ.get(name)
  ```
- The loop at the end can be exited early with
  `if ... not in ...: continue` to remove one level of indentation.
- The `print` should be using function call syntax for forwards
  compatibility with Python 3 and similarly the `except` handler should
  also use the `except ... as e:` syntax instead.  I.e.:

  ```python
  ...
          print(result)
      except mandrill.Error as e:
  ...
  ```
- The iteration over members can use `iteritems` to get both name and
  cards in the same step.
- For the date comparison I'd recommend using a dedicated library, that
  way both the code will be easier to read and one less wheel is
  reinvented.  E.g. I had good experiences with
  [`arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/).
- For the HTTP requests you can also look at
  [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) for a nicer
  interface.

Answer (score 1):

You've done a good job of matching Python style, especially the names. If you haven't already, read the [Python Style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), it's an invaluable resource that comprehensively covers all the style notes.

Organise your imports to be grouped together by type of import: first party, third party and then relative. You also may as well just `import os` rather than importing the whole module for `environ.get` then just grabbing `join` and `dirname`.

When using `.split` to get two elements, it's often neater to using Python's multiple assignment. You can have your split line like this:

```
key, value = member_email_line.split(":")
```

Then `key` and `value` can be used as variables directly:

```
member_emails[key.strip()] = value.strip()
```

It's better to use more applicable names that actually tell you something about what these values are for. Note that if there is more than one colon in the string you'll now get errors when trying to assign this way. This should only be a problem if you

It's more Pythonic not to test for a key's existence when you expect it to be there. Instead, attempt to append to the key and if it doesn't exist catch the error:

```
try:
    members[username].append(card)
except KeyError:
    members[username] = [card]
```

A `KeyError` is raised if `username` isn't in `members`. Since Python's error handling is fast and exceptions aren't going to be very common, your script is faster now.

Lastly, don't use this format for exceptions:

```
except mandrill.Error, e:
```

This was removed in Python3, for good reason. It obfuscates the ability to except multiple exceptions. Imagine this:

```
except KeyError, ValueError:
```

In this case, you catch a `KeyError` with the name `ValueError`. This is confusing behaviour that will throw people off. Instead, use the newer `except Exception as e` syntax, which explicitly references the exception with the name `e`.

```
except mandrill.Error as e:
```